# How to use the buffer_callback in pickle?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to understand how to use the buffer_callback argument in pickle.dumps(). I've read the official python doc and I can follow the example given. But when I try to extend it a bit and do the following:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])

buffers = []
a_bytes = pickle.dumps(a, protocol=5, buffer_callback=buffers.append)
b_bytes = pickle.dumps(b, protocol=5, buffer_callback=buffers.append)
b_loaded = pickle.loads(b_bytes, buffers=buffers)
```

I thought b_loaded should be [5, 6, 7, 8] (and the same object as b), but instead I got [1, 2, 3, 4], which I can verify is actually a. Does it mean I need a separate buffers for each dumps call? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need separate lists of buffers.  The two sets of pickle/unpickle operations are independent.  Combining their out of band data can only cause confusion.  What are you trying to accomplish by doing so?

In this case, each call to `pickle.dumps` stores one out of band buffer to `buffers`.  When `pickle.loads` runs, it knows it needs one out of band buffer, so it pulls that buffer from `buffers`.  It has no reason to know that to restore the second pickle, it should skip one buffer and use the second one in `buffers`.  Why should it?  The buffers in `buffers` are not labeled and are not otherwise distinguishable.  Why would you expect anything else?

You could do this:

```
    b_loaded = pickle.loads(b_bytes, buffers=buffers[1:])
```

but that's kinda silly.  The two pickle/unpickle operations are independent. Just use two lists of buffers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I guess the confusing part is that per the pickle documentation `buffers` should be an iterable. When I load something that's not in the buffer list, such as `pickle.loads(c_bytes, buffers=buffers)`, I get back `c`, not `a`. So obviously some check is being done to see if my input has a buffer in the list. That's why I thought it will somehow match the corresponding buffer. But if you can't use it for multiple objects, isn't just a single buffer object is enough instead of a list? Could you show a code example where the iterable part is used?